# Google chrome addon access all data - Is it a threat?

Tags: security, google-chrome, firefox-extensions

When i install Google chrome extensions "Page Speed " it is saying that it can access all the data in my computer and can access all data of websites am visiting.

Is it a threat?

Can this extension or addon can get all data or  username and password that i am using.

These type of addons of mozilla or chrome have any type of security threat

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's usually safe. You shouldn't install extensions from unreliable sources though.

Chrome restricts extensions from using potentially powerful features, unless the extension has explicitly requested the permissions in a file called `manifest.json`. Many features are grouped, and permissions for a specific function cannot be requested without getting the whole pack of functions (for that group). Hence many extensions need "Access to all browser data" (or something similar).

See [here](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/permission_warnings.html) for a full list of permissions.

Comment: +1 Key point here is to look at the link @Rob has provided and understand it. Also, [here](http://www.google.com/support/chrome_webstore/bin/answer.py?&answer=186213) is a more user-friendly (as opposed to dev-friendly) description of permissions.

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively, you could install the extension (possibly in a VM), navigate to chrome://extensions/, enable "Developer mode".  This will enable an "Inspect popup" menu option and allow you to browse the source code.  Best of luck.